# Take maximum from an array but how to take the corresponding place another array (in R)

Tags: r, arrays

So I have an array with precipitation data which I take the maximum of in the last dimension (hours).
I have also another array with temperature with the same dimensions as the precipitation array, however I want to renew the temperature array by keeping only the temperatures with the corresponding maximum precipitation hours. How can I do this?

I'm thinking about a which.max() command but don't know how to implement this in my question.

Comment: Hello MP. Please read how to [make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it is unfeasible an answer that may help you and others.

Comment: If they are in the same order then dftemp[dfprecip$hrs == max(dfprecip$hrs),] would be one approach, or possibly just joining the tables (`left_join()`) and then `filter()`ing them?